# VBScript error 1004 on Excel Automation

Tags: excel, vbscript, excel-2010, windows-server-2008

I have to move a bunch of VBScript that make use of Excel automation to a new server. I know it is not a reccomended use case for Excel automation, but still this is what I am asked to do.

Most of the times the script works without any changes, but some of them do not work properly.

The old server runs Windows 2003, with Excel 2010 in Italian.

The new server runs Windows 2008 R2, with Excel 2010 in English.

One of the scripts rise an error when executing code similar to this:

```
Option Explicit
On Error Resume Next

Dim objExcel
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Dim xlBook
Set xlBook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("myTemplateFile.xlsm")

WScript.Echo("Error: " & Err.Number & " Description " & Err.Description)

objExcel.Application.Quit
```

The file to open is a "Macro enabled Excel spreadsheet" that on the original (or on my development) machine opens normally. I think I have enabled all Excel option to open spreadsheet with macro, but the code fails with:

> 1004 Unable to get the Open property of the Workbooks class

If I try to open `myTemplateFile.xlsm` in Excel application on the target server, it states that there is some unreadable content and then strips it. The stripped content is the macro source.

Anyone encountered similar problem?

**EDIT**

I can add some other information:

On the source machine is installed the 32-bit version of Office 2010

On the target machine is installed the 64-bit version of Office 2010

I've also noticed that, although macro functionality is enabled and visible in the ribbon, VBA and macro icons are greyed (disabled) also on an empty workbook.

**ANOTHER EDIT**

Just to be clear the following pictures shows the status of the Excel buttons

[image: Disabled Macro Buttons]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It tooks some time to have a definitive proof about the cause of the problem that in the end was very dumb.

Excel was installed on the target server without the VBA functionality.

Once installed from the IT department, Excel no longer strips away macro and VBA content, and the script can successfully execute `Workbooks.Open`